# Is it possible to upload file without input type="file"

Tags: php, html

I want to use a text-box, insert my file address is in the Desktop, and then upload it in the server, what should I do?

Comment: No you need input type file

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you dont like file uploader object how it looks?
If yes I suggest you to make it hidden but in background use its fuctionality.
Show file selected information in a textbox but keep the file into hidden file uploder object.

Another method to post files like audio and jpeg to server is  to use Base64 format . Its consider as string but not recommanded for large files.
Then you need a backend function to save data into file object or simply insert data into database.

Answer (score -2):

Do it this way:

```
$file_url= $_POST['file'];   //Path of file to be uploaded


if file_exists($file_url):
     $fh= fopen("NewfileName", a+);
     fwrite($fh, file_get_contents($file_url));
    fclose($fh);
endif;
```

Comment: **Undefined index**: `C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\1.png in /var/www/html/Upload.php`

Comment: Please lemme see the upload.php file

Comment: Where do you think the file is?

Comment: @Abolarin stephen       <?php
 $file = 'C:\Users\MyPc\Desktop\1.png'; 
 $file_url= $_POST[$file];   //Path of file to be uploaded
 var_dump($_POST[$file]);
?>

Comment: The $_POST is used to contain data submitted through the post method. Since the file path was not submitted through a POST form you can't get it from the post index. You can create a form with input name file to submit to your upload.php. For file uploads stick with the input type=file tag and get the file data using *$_FILE*

Comment: @Abolarin stephen   How can I submit the data from text box, not input type=file

Comment: I know how to upload with  `input type=file` but I have to not use `input type=file`

Comment: Use the *<textarea name="file"></textarea>* In your PHP Fetch the file url using $_POST['file']. Your form method must be post

Comment: @Abolarin stephen   Would you explain more about `<textarea name="file"></textarea>`